# Returning string from a function causing formatting issues

Tags: c++, arrays, string, loops

It's supposed to look like this: http://i.imgur.com/gko501E.png

Instead it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEoNN.png

When I take the code out of the function and use it in the main class it works properly. However once I put it in this function the formatting problems occur, it also isn't filtering like it's supposed to. This program is supposed to take user input, store it in a string, remove all non-alphabetical characters, capitalize the vowels, and then space it out based on user defined variables given in the command line. It's also supposed to accept files as input in the command line, such as: 'program 5 8 < file'.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

//make vowels uppercase
string filter(string input)
{
    size_t found = input.find_first_of("aeiou");

    while (found != string::npos)
    {
        if (islower(input[found]))
        {
            input[found] = toupper(input[found]);
            found = input.find_first_of("aeiou", found + 1);
        }
    }

    //Make consonants lowercase

    size_t foundLower = input.find_first_of("BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ");

    while (foundLower != string::npos)
    {
        if (isupper(input[foundLower]))
        {
            input[foundLower] = tolower(input[foundLower]);
            foundLower = input.find_first_of("BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ", foundLower + 1);
        }
    }

    //remove punctuation
    for (int i = 0, len = input.size(); i < len; i++)
    {
        if (!isalnum(input[i]))
        {
            input.erase(i--, 1);
            len = input.size();
        }
    }

    return input;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int wordSize;
    int wordSizeCounter;
    int wordCounter = 0;
    int rowSize;
    //char letter;

    wordSize = atoi(argv[1]);
    rowSize = atoi(argv[2]);

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(argv[3]);//open the input file

    stringstream strStream;
    strStream << inFile.rdbuf();//read the file
    string test = strStream.str();//str holds the content of the file
    if (!inFile) test = cin.get() ;             //   Read first character



    //Begin filter for files

    while (!test.empty())
    {
        filter(test);

        if (test.length() < wordSize) //make sure we don't go out-of-bounds
        {
            wordSize = test.length();
        }

        cout << test.substr(0, wordSize);
        cout << " ";

        if (test.length() >= wordSize) //again, make sure we don't go out-of-bounds
        {
            test = test.substr(wordSize);
        }
        else
        {
            test = " ";
        }

        wordCounter++;
        if (wordCounter == rowSize)
        {
            cout << std::endl;
            wordCounter = 0;
        }

        if(test.empty())
        {
            test = cin.get();
        }
    }


    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you gone to debug mode and stepped thru the code? What do you see?

Comment: I don't know how to use a debugger. When I run through it doesn't give me any errors.

Comment: Then add some instrumentation, ie code that displays values at certain points during the process.  And choose a short text sample. Then look at the data as it progresses from one step to another...

Comment: Interestingly the filter is actually doing what it's supposed to. It is changing the string. At least when it's in the function. I'll keep trying.

Comment: Okay, it's not returning the string.

Comment: which was? please tell us